# Axios mock adapter server returns a 404 ERROR

Tags: reactjs, axios, axios-mock-adapter

I have data in a local `JSON` file; to query that data, I'm using `axios-mock-adapter`. But for some reason, it's giving `404 not found`. Not sure what I'm missing

Exact error: `GET http://localhost:3000/api/results 404 (Not Found)`

I have created a `db folder` with all the files below.

`mock.js` file

```
const MockAdapter = require('axios-mock-adapter');
const axios = require('axios');
const Mock = new MockAdapter(axios.create());
export default Mock;
```

`index.js` file

```
import Mock from './mock';
import './db/database';

Mock.onAny().passThrough();
```

`database.js` file

```
import Mock from "../mock";

    const database = {
      results: {
        books: [
          name: "loren ipsum",
        ],
      },
    };
    
    Mock.onGet("/api/results").reply((config) => {
      const response = database.results;
      console.log("mock results", response);
      return [200, response];
    });
```

and then in my components:

I am querying it like this:

```
const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const request = await axios.get("/api/results").then((response) => {
        console.log("res", response.data);
        console.log("request", request);
        setBooks(request);
      });
      return request;
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```